# Does the Browse only close Ribbon Menu?

Tags: ribbon, menu

In SharePoint 2013, is the Browse option in the Ribbon Menu only supposed to close the ribbon menu? Or, is it suppose to open it as well?

Currently, when the Ribbon Menu is closed, the Browse option **does not open the menu.** However, when I select Task and List, the Ribbon Menu opens and **then the Browser option closes the ribbon menu.**

[image: Screen Shot of Browse Ribbon Menu]

Comment: By ribbon menu you mean the actions you can perform under Tasks and Lists? If yes, than the Browse option is only supposed to close the ribbon menu.

Comment: The ribbon opens up the relevant menu to where/on what you clicked. It's supposed to close the ribbon while expanded. 

Click on a page, you get the page tab in the ribbon, click on a list and you get item/lists ribbon. That's it. :)